# Unknow Zip file of ~60gb created in Weblogic folder and now HDD partition is full

Tags: linux, rhel, weblogic

We are currently deploying applications in Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 and while deployment,
the deployment failed with the error that no space is available for copying stage files.
OS = Redhat Enterprise Linux 8.3
Java = 1.8.251

On analysis, we found that a zip file has been created in the Weblogic directory of ~60GB, which was the size of the total available space in that partition.

We had faced a same issue last week when all the adjacent folders were also deleted and only the zip file was left there. Back then the admin guys just reinstalled a fresh Weblogic after not finding any RCA.
But this time the folders have not been deleted, just the HDD space is full.

Can anyone help understand why this issue is occurring or if anyone else has faced something like this?

Highlighted below the zip file that was created in Weblogic folder.

[image]

Comment: The permissions on the file (`-r-----rw`) and the empty filename (`.zip`) points to a missing configuration option in Weblogic. What's in `.zip`?

Comment: We are unable to extarct the zip file, and getting the error ===  "End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive."

Comment: What does `file .zip` say the file is? You could `mv .zip a.zip` to make it easier. Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].